# Binary and shared library compatability across different versions of the same Linux distribution

Tags: linux, compatibility

Suppose I have shared libraries and binaries compiled on Linux distribution X ver N. 
Will it work on the same distribution ver N+1?.

What are the general rules to determine this? (e.g. gcc/glibc version, maybe it's distribution specific, LSB etc.)

Answer (score 3):

First, check external dependencies of your binaries and libraries:

```
ldd yourlib.so a.out ...
```

The sample output is

```
  librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f7906ee6000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7906b29000)
  libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f790690b000)
```

And then check if required libraries are not significantly changed in N+1: determine packages that own these libraries (`rpm -qf file` or `dpkg -S file`) and compare versions (N and N+1) of found packages in [upstream-tracker](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/).

Finally, check if the version of gcc is not changed significantly (from 2.x to 3.y or from 3.x to 4.y).

Also, try to use [Linux Application Checker](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/lsb/all-about-linux-application-checker) on all your binaries against N+1 version of the distribution if it's supported by the tool.

[image]